# 'Uncaught TypeError' only on first page load only in Chrome on desktop. Works on second or more page loads. What is happening?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, typeerror, session-storage

I have this problem that only exists on first page load in Chrome on desktop. It works in Chrome on the second or more page loads. It also works on mobile in Chrome on every page load.

It works fine in Safari and Firefox, MOST OF THE TIME. I have experienced the below error there as well, only on first page load, only on desktop, but I am not able to reproduce it there for about an entire day now.

Does anyone know what is going on?

The only thing I have been able to come up with is that somehow my `redirect` function is triggered. Because as you can see in the flow indicated below at number 6, after the error, the page redirects back to index.html. However that function would only trigger if the value of one of my sessionStorage values is `null` and I can see in the browser console that those values are set correctly when I press the button to go to the next page.

**The error:**

[image: pic of error code]

**The flow:**

1. Landing page is index.html with separate index.js
2. Upon selection of a few drop-downs, 3 values are stored in sessionStorage
3. Next page is called: normal-quiz.html with separate normal-quiz.js
4. Values from sessionStorage are retrieved to filter a data array
5. The loadQuiz function runs on the filtered array and sets a question element value to an object's 'english' property
6. On first page load, only in Chrome on desktop, the above error occurs which makes the browser return to index.html and sessionStorage is cleared
7. If I try the above again, it works without a problem

The line generating the error is where I use the loadQuiz function to set the question element's value in my html to the 'english' property value of the first object in the filtered array.

**The code (js):**

```
function redirect() {
if (selectedBook !== null) {
    // do nothing
} else {
    window.location = "<myURL>"
};
};

redirect();

function loadQuiz() {
const currentQuizData = quizArr[currentQuiz]; // currentQuiz is the question counter. It starts at 0 to get the first object, then increments by 1 after each question

questionEl.innerText = currentQuizData.english;
// line above is where the error is generated

counter.innerText = (currentQuiz + 1) + "/" + quizArr.length;
};
loadQuiz();
```

Comment: We would need more code to be able to help. It seems that you are not getting what you expect from the storage. There may be a problem with the execution order of your code. Also, are you handling the case when storage is cleared?

Comment: @ErnestoStifano I think you already helped me by mentioning execution order. I didn't know about that yet. Perhaps my redirect function (see above) is executing before the sessionStorage web API can get the stored values. I disabled the redirect and ran a test. It seems to work then. If that was indeed it, isn't it strange that it only happens in Chrome on desktop and only on first load? What do you mean by 'case when storage is cleared'?

Comment: I would need to see how you are inserting JS in your HTML files and also how your code works (if you are using some kind of event or a particular method that provokes asynchronous execution, for example). As a general rule, consider that each browser (or browser engine) handles pages loading in its own way, even if there are standards, there are some grey areas. If you point me to a working example or repo maybe I can help you better.

Comment: @ErnestoStifano here is my GitHub repo: https://github.com/bassieee/test.ficka. The repo works for me everywhere without a problem. I have exactly the same code hosted on Google Cloud Storage on this domain: https://ficka.io/. However on that domain, the above described error occurs in Chrome on first page load. It redirects because my redirect function is triggered. If I disable that, the error in the screenshot above occurs. I think it might be because it starts executing all the code before it gets the sessionStorage, but I am not sure. Thank you for wanting to have a look, if you can.

Comment: Will take a look and then get back to you